# String replace in python confuses . with E?

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to remove all "M. " that appears in the beginning of a column. This is supposed to be easy. Here is my code:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('M. ', "", regex=True)
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
name
M. ABAD John
M. BOULMÉ Jean
Mme BONO-VANDORME Anne
```

This is what I am obtaining:

```
name
ABAD Jogn
BOULJean
Mme BONO-VANDORAnne
```

I find this result very weird. It seems that python is confusing "E" with ".". Why is this happening? How should I correct the code?

Comment: In regex `.` matches any character.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions if you don't understand regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas `str.replace()` method is different from the Python Built-in `str.replace()` in that str.replace considers its first argument as a regular expression.

In regular expression the dot `.` represents any single character, therefore the string `ME`  matches the regular expression `M.`

Therefore the solution in your case would be to disable treating the first argument as a regular expression.

With `regex=False` `str.replace` would perform a normal character string substitution.

```py
df['name'].str.replace('M. ', '', regex=False)
```

Note that in the latest versions of Pandas (since pandas 2.0) `regex=False` is the default, so you could just avoid this optional argument altogether. Yet beware that in earlier versions the default was exactly the opposite.

Comment: @MatBailie this became the default since Pandas 2.0. There are too many environments around with the earlier versions.